# Spring session replication with mongodb not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

I am replicating session using mongodb

below is the configuration I am using

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoHttpSession
public class MongoSessionReplication {

@Bean
public AbstractMongoSessionConverter mongoSessionConverter() {
    List<Module> securityModules = SecurityJackson2Modules.getModules(getClass().getClassLoader());
    return new JacksonMongoSessionConverter(securityModules);
}
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(@Qualifier("replicaSet") Datastore replicaSet){
   MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(replicaSet.getMongo(),replicaSet.getDB().getName());
   return mongoTemplate;
}

}
```

Now everything is working fine except the `Principal` object that spring security creates after loggin in.
I have custom implementation of `UserDetails`

```
public class PortalUser extends User {

    private String primaryEmailId;

    private String redirectUrl;

    public PortalUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    }
    public PortalUser(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, true, true, true, true, authorities);
    }

    public String getPrimaryEmailId() {
        return primaryEmailId;
    }

    public void setPrimaryEmailId(String primaryEmailId) {
        this.primaryEmailId = primaryEmailId;
    }

    public String getRedirectUrl() {
        return redirectUrl;
    }

    public void setRedirectUrl(String redirectUrl) {
        this.redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
    }
}
```

Below is `UserDetailsService`

```
@Service
public class PortalUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private SSOServiceAPI ssoServiceAPI;

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileService userProfileService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String hexId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserProfile userProfile = userProfileService.getUserProfileByUserId(hexId);
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthority = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        if(userProfile!=null) {
            grantedAuthority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userProfile.getSsmRoles().name()));
        } else {
            grantedAuthority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        }
        SSOUsers ssoUser = ssoServiceAPI.findSSOUser(hexId, false);
        PortalUser portalUser = new PortalUser(hexId, hexId, true, true, true, true, grantedAuthority);
        portalUser.setPrimaryEmailId(ssoUser.getPrimaryUserId());
        return portalUser;

    }
}
```

Controller

```
public String getAllProducts(@RequestParam(value = "callback", required = true) String callback, Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String hexId = principal.getName();
    String primaryEmailId = ((PortalUser) ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal).getPrincipal()).getPrimaryEmailId(); //----->> this line fails

}
```

Above highlighted typecasting failed as it returns instance of `UserDetails` instead of my custom `PortalUser`. But this isn't a case when I disable spring-session replication..

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Spring's Security  UserDetails, not User.

update MyUser to the below:

```
public class SecUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public SecUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```

Comment: Jeryl Thanks for your reply.
`User` itself implements `UserDetails`.

Comment: hi Amit, do you mean "User" extends UserDetails?